# Submit button requires two clicks to submit

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, submit

I made a short jquery script to confirm user is entering same password twice. The submit button there by default is in an inactive state. If user enters matching password, jquery ().html() reqrites the button ro an active one.

This all works fine but user needs to hit button twice for it to process the form. How can I fix this so the browser (been testing in chrome) can register the first click:

element

```
<div id="notif"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info    disabled">Submit</button></div>
```

js

```
<script>
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();
if (password != confirmPassword)
    $("#notif").html("<button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger disabled'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Submit</button><p style='margin-left: 10px; color:#FF0000; font-weight: bold; display: inline;'>Passwords Do Not Match</p>");
else
    $("#notif").html("<button type='submit' class='btn btn-success active'><i class='fa fa-check'></li> Submit</button>");
                                }
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
                                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to just enable the `button` rather than using `.html()`.Perhaps something like this.Also add the `disabled` attribute in the button html

```
var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();
if (password != confirmPassword)
    $("#notif").html("<button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger disabled'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Submit</button><p style='margin-left: 10px; color:#FF0000; font-weight: bold; display: inline;'>Passwords Do Not Match</p>");
else
    $("#notif").find("button").attr("disabled",false);
                                }
```

Also please provide a fiddle if possible.